# Как решить проблемму с php и session?

Tags: php

```
<?
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
header("Location:http://sait.ru/id".$_SESSION['id']);
}
else {
```

print <<<END

Тут код хтмл страницы

END;

```
}
?>
```

Ошибка

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header
> information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/live-inves/live-invest.ru/docs/index.php:1)
> in
> /home/live-inves/live-invest.ru/docs/index.php
> on line 4

И

> **Warning**: session_start() [*function.session-start*]: Cannot
> send session cache limiter - headers
> already sent (output started at
> /home/sait/sait.ru/docs/index.php:1)
> in /home/sait/sait.ru/docs/index.php
> on line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_start` и `header` должны вызываться до любого вывода (echo, print etc). Если это у вас реальное начало файла, проверьте кодировку, должна быть "utf-8 без BOM". Если сомневаетесь, откройте в hex-редакторе файл, перед `<?` будет 2 байта.

Comment: кто вам такое сказал???

Comment: Но заработало же))

Comment: Мозг и [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)

> Замечание:
> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых вам надо бы подучить английский, так как прочитав сведения об ошибке, вы бы сразу все поняли. По поводу сессий - просто уберите session_start(). У вас на сервере сессии стартуют автоматически...

Comment: Автостарт сессии - большая редкость, если только сам не выставил.