# Какой PHP framework выбрать?

Tags: framework, php

Какой фреймворк выбрать для большого проекта который требует:

1. безопасности
2. быстроты разработки
3. гибкости

Comment: Сейчас каждый придёт и назовёт что-то своё. Я вот увидел Kohana и влюбился с первой строчки :)

Comment: Может дадим парню медаль "за розжиг холивара"?

Comment: согласен))))

Comment: Понять принцип framework'а, для чего он предназначен, продумать структуру, задачи. Почитать про PDO, сесть и написать свой!

Comment: Бери MODx не промахнешься !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend FrameWork

Answer (score 3):

Таких вопросов было огромное количество.
И из всех обсуждений однозначно надо выбирать то что вам более знакомо и более близко по структуре и стилю программирования.
Фреймворк это инструмент и выбирать его надо под себя в первую очередь.

Answer (score 1):

Если в перспективе хотите, что-то достойное писать и вообще стать профессионалом, то Symfony2, а если побаловаться, то что-нить по проще ;)

Answer (score 1):

[compare php frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/)
на хабре [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50341/)
или вот [тоже интересно](http://tvorzasp.com/blog/mikrofrejmvorki-na-php)

линки даю, чтобы холивара небыло :)

Answer (score 0):

Я в свое время тоже выбирал, для сравнения решил написать небольшой блог на 3-х framework:Zend FrameWork,Symfony,YII. Быстрее всего и качественнее получилось на YII, теперь в основном использую его, иногда подключая либы из Zend. Как на меня YII намного гибче остальных, в этом его основной плюс, но тут как говорится: "На вкус и цвет....."

Comment: а можете выложить все 3 проекта, дать возможность сравнить код другим? :)

Answer (score -2):

Совсем не в тему вопроса: я бы протестовал против всех фреймворков, раз вопрос поставлен так, и не советовал бы использовать ни один кроме собственного. До того, как начнёте поливать грязью - читайте дальше.

- безопасность. У меня есть такое предположение, пинайте если я не прав - если вы не умеете самостоятельно писать безопасный код, то ни один фреймворк Вам жизни не сделает.
- быстрота разработки. Этот пункт вызывает большущий резонанс, которым меня кроет: почему-то, не знаю почему, скорость разработки на том, что напишите Вы самостоятельно будет гораздо выше чем на каком-либо фреймворке (Не сочтите за невежество или оскорбление, но в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72892/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-php-%D0%B8-session) вопросе видны Ваши знания и я всё-же придерживаюсь такого мнения, что фреймворк нужен для быстрой разработки, а затем и деплоймента, но никак не для обучения). Опять возвращаемся к моему ответу на пункт №1.
- гибкость. Что вы имеете ввиду под гибкостью?

Comment: а как на счет командной разработке крупных проектов на "собственном" фреймворке?

Comment: @digi, а я ничего не говорил про командную разработку. Были чисто персональные рекомендации "Не сочтите за невежество или оскорбление, но в этом вопросе видны Ваши знания и я всё-же придерживаюсь такого мнения, что фреймворк нужен для быстрой разработки, а затем и деплоймента, но никак не для обучения".

Comment: по личному опыт скажу, что правильные мышление появилось не в результате сибственных разработок, а только после начала освноения Symfony2, притом сначала начал посмотривать идеи и пытаться переносить в свой проект, потом понял, что компоненты ипользовать вполне резонно и только потом понял красоту всех решений, что предлагает проект симфони :)

Comment: @digi, не могу рассудить адекватно, опираясь на словесное описание. 

>правильные мышление появилось не в результате сибственных разработок, а только после начала освноения Symfony2
>***
>"Я поехал на сдутых колёсах, но потом подумал и решил всё-таки поставить себе зимнюю резину"

Я вижу это как-то так.

Comment: То, что фреймворк в кривых руках не будет безопасен, нельзя считать корректным аргументом - самописное решение в тех же руках будет и вовсе ужасным. 

Быстрота разработки? Писать проект параллельно с фреймворком быстрее не получится. Не параллельно - тем более. Сторонняя разработка разрабатывается без вас, другие программисты могут её изучить и эти знания им будут более полезны.